# Error in installing connect-mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, npm, connect-mongo

****When I try to install connect-mongo or connect-mongo@0.4.1 I am getting this error , when I try installing express or other features , I never got this error ,What I can do to avoid this error.

Before this I installed 
1.express
2.hogan-express
3.cookie-parser
4.express-session
And for connecting my production session with database I tried connect-mongo as well as mongoose .Both shows error which is same as this one.

For information: I already tried installing 1st and 2nd option it is not getting installed , I have upgraded version already in my OS.

I couldn't attach my image here so I copy pasted the content from command prompt

```
    C:\Users\Desktop\Chatbox>npm install connect-mongo@0.4.1 --save
    npm WARN package.json chatbox@1.0.0 No repository field.
    npm WARN package.json chatbox@1.0.0 No README data
    |
    > kerberos@0.0.3 install C:\Users\Desktop\Chatbox\node_modules\connect-m
    ongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos
    > (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

   C:\Users\Desktop\Chatbox\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb
    \node_modules\kerberos>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program File
    s\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node
    -gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
    Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
    please add the "/m" switch.
    MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
     To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visua
    l Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it
    is installed elsewhere.  [C:\Users\Desktop\Chatbox\node_modules\connect
    -mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos\build\binding.sln]

    > bson@0.2.5 install C:\Users\Desktop\Chatbox\node_modules\connect-mongo
    \node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson
    > (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


    C:\Users\Desktop\Chatbox\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb
    \node_modules\bson>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\no
    dejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp
    .js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
    Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
    please add the "/m" switch.
    MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
     To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visua
    l Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it
    is installed elsewhere.  [C:\Users\Desktop\Chatbox\node_modules\connect
    -mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson\build\binding.sln]
    connect-mongo@0.4.1 node_modules\connect-mongo
    └── mongodb@1.3.23 (kerberos@0.0.3, bson@0.2.5)
```

I appreciate your efforts,
Thank you in advance.****

Comment: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
     To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK. Try to install `.NET Framework` update

Comment: I tried it , its not working .Moreover it wont get installed since my os has upgraded version already.

Answer (score 1):

Complete these three steps as mentioned in the log above and you will be good to go.

1. install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK,
2. install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or
3. add the location of the component to the system path if it is
   installed elsewhere.

Comment: I already have higher version of step 1 and step2 add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere - it means it is installed in c drive rite.I already done it.If some other thing please give me suggestions.